# Group by distinct values from Prometheus Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

My query results in a table view in Grafana,

`max by (instance) (system_uptime{instance=~"abcd.*"})`,

there are multiple rows for each instance in the resulting table.

Is there a way to group the result by distinct instance name and get the max value of up-time for each instance, please let me know

Answer (score 3):

Enable the "Instant" option in the query screen of Grafana.
Only Distinct values will get reported